# Flutter - validate the form for the number

Tags: flutter, dart

Many peoples validate the Form for numbers using the property/widget of TextFormField() widget like
**keyboardType: TextInputType.number** But I have a question that can we validate the Form only to prevent the Alphabets and punctuation marks from the Form and keeps the text of FormFiled String (numbers) ? is It possible ? If you have any logic for this please share it.

Comment: You want to have the user input as String even if the TextFormField accepts only numbers? I din't quite get what you were asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the `keyboardType` property is set to `TextInputType.phone` the text of the form field will be `string` and not `num`.
For further validation, use the `validator` property.

Answer (score 0):

TextField had inputFormatter. Just add this line inside the text field widget

```
  inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>. 
          [WhitelistingTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly], // Only numbers are allowed
```